# Add more than one keyboard shortcut for an action in GNOME

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, gnome3

How can I **map *additional* shortcuts** to an action, **without losing the existing shortcuts** for that action?

I have some computers running GNOME version 3 with multiple keyboards (e.g. a notebook computer which is sometimes used with an external keyboard).

These keyboards provide different keys (e.g. some notebook computers don't have the separate cursor movement keys, instead providing only a number pad with these functions) and the keys available for shortcuts are therefore different on the same computer.

So for some commands (e.g. `Switch to Previous Tab`) I need to configure an *additional* keyboard shortcut (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Number pad Page Up</kbd>) *without* replacing the existing shortcut for that function.

I need a way to **add a shortcut** without replacing existing ones. How can I do that?

Comment: Please state which version of Gnome you are using.

Comment: Dan: Already did, please see the question text.

Comment: You could add a custom shortcut for the extra key combos, which just simulates the key presses for the main shortcut.

Comment: This probably belongs on Unix.SE.

Comment: I'm thinking that such may require movomg the functionality to an external program or set of programs. 
 Example: for browsers, this can be done via Gleebox, Surfingkeys, Vimperator, or similar.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can accomplish this in the Keyboard settings GUI, but you can [use a `dconf` editor](https://askubuntu.com/a/575482/39012).

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Super>Page_Down','<Control><Alt>Down']"
```

Don't forget the wrapping double-quotes as my system was giving me an `unknown keyword` error without them.